# Scikit : How to choose alpha of multinomailNB

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have written a spam filter using `Scikit`. For this I am using `MultinomialNB with alpha = 0.1` . 
Can any one explain me in layman terms what is alpha (smoothing factor) and how can I choose value of it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the wikipedia page
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing.

Basically the idea is that you want to decrease the effect of rare words: for example if you have one spam email with the word 'multinomialNB' in it, and no nonspam emails with this word, then without additive smoothing, your spam filter will classify every email with this keyword as spam.

Comment: So can I say if alpha = 1 would suppress the affect of rare words more than alpha = 0.1 ??